# Color quantization diluting pure whites

Tags: java, graphics, colors, java-2d, quantization

I have a simple quantization function

```
public static int quantize(int oldpixel) {

    int r = (oldpixel >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g = (oldpixel >> 8) & 0xff;
    int b = (oldpixel >> 0) & 0xff;

    int color = 0xff << 24 | (((int) ((r) / 32) * 32) & 0xff) << 16 | 
            (((int) ((g) / 32) * 32) & 0xff) << 8 | 
            (((int) ((b) / 32) * 32)& 0xff) << 0;
    return color;
}
```

What it does is reduce a color to a lower detail color, then expands it, this artificially limits the pallet and I'll use it for a dither filter, an image through the function produces this

In:
[Unquantized hue wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yKK3.png)
Out:
[Quantized hue wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yKK3.png)

This is almost perfect as the result, except the whites are reduced to a gray, I understand the cause is my flooring of divided colors in the algorithm, but I do not know how to fix this, any suggestions would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of `/ 32 * 32`, try `/ 32 * 33`.

Comment: 33 helps marginally, after playing with it a bit 36 is the higher limit and produces near white, though inspection with a color select tool shows its not quite, but this will work well as a temporary workaround as it does not affect black, thank you!

Comment: Actually yes, 36 would be correct for 8 levels. (I was thinking of *17 for 16 levels)

Comment: Really you want to do `/ 32 * (255.0 / 7.0)` which happens to be about 36.428, but it's not an integer.

Comment: By the way, those `(int)` casts are redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dividing each component by 32, you have an integer between 0 and 7. You are trying to map this back to the range 0 to 255, so that 0 is 0 and 7 is 255.

You can do this by multiplying it by 255/7, which happens to be about 36.428.

You could use something like `(int)((r / 32) * (255.0 / 7.0))`, but the cast is ugly in Java. To improve that you could wrap it in a function, and have `quantizeChannel(r)`, `quantizeChannel(g)` and `quantizeChannel(b)`. Or you could swap the order and use integer arithmetic: `r / 32 * 255 / 7`.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it, it works perfectly now